# How to set accordion-height to a fixed value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

How to set the jQuery UI Accordion -height to a fixed value?
Did I miss anything?

Comment: By default, the accordion's height is equal to the height of it's tallest child. Is this not the behavior you want? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have a absolutely positioned element in there so jQuery can't measure the content-height correct. (/it seems like so)

Comment: Okay I got it to work by putting an static positioned div with a fixed height into the background.

But it would be still interesting if there is a jQuery solution to this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See this example: http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#no-auto-height

**Edit**

Actually, you probably want this: http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#default

Comment: Yea works onload, but when I click the accordion my fixed heigh is gone. I also tried in combination with clearstyle.